# Closed form of S(n):

Tags: number-theory, graph-theory

The following problem is about a game played with wooden blocks stacked vertically.

The way the game is played is as so:

1. There is a stack of *n* blocks available on a table in front of you;
2. With every move you make you can split the stack into two piles which, under your choice, can be equal or not;
3. After every move, your score is increased based on the product of the sizes of the two new stacks;
4. The game is played until all stacks are of size **1**;
5. The sum of all the products is the total score.

The following is a simulation of 8 blocks:

\begin{align}
8\quad \longrightarrow \quad { 4 }_{ 1 }\quad and\quad { 4 }_{ 2 }\quad =\quad (4\quad \cdot \quad 4)\quad =\quad 16\\ { 4 }_{ 1 }\quad \longrightarrow \quad 3\quad and\quad 1\quad =\quad (3\quad \cdot \quad 1)\quad =\quad 3\\ { 4 }_{ 2 }\quad \longrightarrow \quad { 2 }_{ 1 }\quad and\quad { 2 }_{ 2 }\quad =\quad (2\quad \cdot \quad 2)\quad =\quad 4\\ 3\quad \longrightarrow \quad { 2 }_{ 3 }\quad and\quad 1\quad =\quad (2\quad \cdot \quad 1)\quad =\quad 2\\ { 2 }_{ 1 }\quad \longrightarrow \quad 1\quad and\quad 1\quad =\quad (1\quad \cdot \quad 1)\quad =\quad 1\\ { 2 }_{ 2 }\quad \longrightarrow \quad 1\quad and\quad 1\quad =\quad (1\quad \cdot \quad 1)\quad =\quad 1\\ { 2 }_{ 3 }\quad \longrightarrow \quad 1\quad and\quad 1\quad =\quad (1\quad \cdot \quad 1)\quad =\quad 1\\ \\ \text{Total Score} =\quad 16+3+4+2+1+1+1\quad =\quad 28
\end{align}

Let *S(n)* represent the maximum score one could possibly achieve playing this game with *n* blocks.

What are different ways of deriving the closed form of S(n)?

Comment: I think the best strategy is always dividing stacks as equally as possible.

Comment: @Gamamal Think so? Try simulating the a stack of blocks through your method, and through an arbitrary other one.

Comment: When starting with $8$ blocks and using my method you get a score of $28$

Comment: Do you have a counterexample?

Comment: In fact can you find a way to split them up that gives a number different than $28$?

Comment: @Gamamal No, can you prove your method provides a maximum?

Comment: In fact it turns out no matter how you play the game your score is always going to be $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. It's impossible to do better or worse.

Comment: @Gamamal Great observation.

Comment: $S(x)=\max\limits_{i} (S(i)+S(x-i)+i(x-i)),\ S(1)=0$

Answer (score 2):

No matter how you play the game if you start with a stack of $n$ piles your score is always going to be $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.

When we play the game for every step we add $a\cdot b$ where $a$ and $b$ are the sizes of the stacks we obtain after dividing a stack of size $a+b$. $a\cdot b$ is the same as going block by block and for each block adding the number of blocks from which it got separated (So if we consider a block in the pile of size $a$ we add $b$). If we do this we obtain $2ab$. So adding $a\cdot b$ is the same as going through each of the $a+b$ blocks and adding from how many blocks the block in question got separated and then dividing this by $2$.

So at the end of the game the final score is equal to the sum of from how many blocks each block got separated divided by two. Of course by the end of the game each block will have been separated from $n-1$ other blocks. This means the final score is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$

Comment: This method is one of the most straightforward ways to go about this problem, and is correct. well done :) Can you think of many other indirect ways of proving this?

Comment: wait, you already knew the solution?

Comment: Why yes I do, but that is why I asked for the different ways of deriving it. I'm trying to find out if there are other indirect ways that come to the same conclusion.

Comment: Oh I see, I will try :). Very nice problem.

Comment: @Gamamal: good point, we simply calculate the number of edges in $K_n$ as every turn (dividing to $k$ and $n-k$) "breaks" $E(K_k)\cdot E(K_{n-k})$ edges.

Comment: Oh, that is a really nice way to see it Alexey Burdin.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Which is why I tagged graph theory. ;)